# Find active tab in UITabBarController

Tags: uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on a radio streaming app with 2 UITabBarController buttons at the bottom of the app. One for Live Streaming and one for Top 40 list.

I'm using a common StreamingViewController for both the tabs. But depending on the tab selected - a different url needs to be passed to the StreamingViewController so that it can play the appropriate feed.

So how can i determine the active tab ?

Answer (score 50):

Did you even look at the documentation? `tabBarController.selectedIndex` will give you the index of the selected tab, and `tabBarController.selectedViewController` will give you a pointer to the view controller at the active tab.

Comment: i tried that - but failed .. 
this is what im doing - basically when the "Play" button is pressed in the StreamingViewController.xib in the .m file im checking 
if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) { // load url with url for live stream and play audio}

if(tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1 ) {// load url for Top40 list and play audio}

i tried printing the value of selectedIndex with nslog and it always shows 0.

Comment: If you've already tried that, you should say so in your question. Saves us work and gives you a better answer. Have you confirmed that `tabBarController` is valid?

Comment: I'm sorry for that ... How can i check if tabBarController is valid ?

Comment: Go through the code with the debugger, type `po tabBarController` and check if it returns `nil` or an actual object. If the former, you know where you have to look for the error.

Comment: yes it is valid ... i am getting some hex value ... ok i think i shud get into the exact details of my problem in AppDelegate_iPhone I programatically created a UITabBarController called rootController. Then using IB i gave the two tabs their titles and i set their class to StreamingViewController and assigned the same xib. In StreamingViewController.h i created an object for AppDelegate_iphone called indexChecker. in viewDidLoad for StreamingViewController i wrote the if conditions mentioned b4.

Comment: the cinditions i used are indexChecker.rootController.selectedIndex ==0 and indexChecker.rootController.selectedIndex==1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from where you are calling the code to load the URL, but you probably need to be notified when the user selects a different tab.  Override your UITabBarController class, and implement didSelectViewController method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

In this method, you should be able to pass the appropriate URL to your controller.

(I know this answer is kind of late, but I hope it helps)

Answer (score 0):

So I stumbled upon this question as my app required the same functionality. The answer is : You can find active tab by **tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.title** this will give you title of active tab or you can use **tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag** if you have assigned tags to your tabBar Items. Hope it helps others from pulling their hair :P